# Charset UTF-8 composed/decomposes in HTTP Respose Header

Tags: http, encoding, utf-8, content-type, unicode-normalization

Does anybody know if there is a ways to inform clients of a web service if the delivered UTF-8 content is normalised or not?

I'm thinking about something like sending a Response Header with

`Content-Type: application/json;charset="UTF-8 decomposed"` or

`Content-Type: application/json;charset="UTF-8 composed"`.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

a) application/json doesn't have a charset parameter. Introducing it here for something that isn't a charset name seems like a bad idea.

b) Why would the client care? What is it supposed to do with that information?

Comment: a) `application/json` does have UTF-8 as default charset. You're right, it's not necessary to declare that explicitly.

b) If you work with the data (especially when you compare strings) it's necessary to normalise the string before. It would be helpful if you know that before.

Comment: It doesn't really have a default charset; it could be UTF-16 or UTF-32 as well (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-8.1), but yet, UTF-8 is preferred.

Comment: Okay, but informing the client about normalisation is not possible/designated!?

Comment: It's not specified, and I really don't see how that helps; you can easily check on the recipient side, whereas an outbound signal might be incorrect, and your code would do the wrong thing then.

Comment: Wouldn't it be helpful if the server is telling "I'm sending decomposed or composed UTF-8, normalised in NFC, NFD, NFKC, NFKC". Our API could provide this information (always correct) and I'd be happy if I could share that with the clients/users.